# How can one plot a grid within a for loop?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

I'm implementing a [Kohonen self-organising map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map), which consists of a $3 \times 3$ grid with a $4$-neighbour topology.

I've created a for loop that sets the values of the learning coefficients (which are dependent on the iteration index), updates the network accordingly and then is supposed to plot the resulting grid. 
The issue is that the grid doesn't show when the plotting function `plotgrid` is called within the for loop, but it does show when `plotgrid` is called outside the function.

I've searched for issues relating to function calls which don't work within loops, but haven't found any useful advice, and I think I might be missing something simple.

In short, I'm trying to plot a single grid which changes with each iteration of the for loop, showing the current state of the network.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this?

EDIT: I've just found this [post on plotting inside Mathematica modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686742/show-plots-inside-module-in-mathematica). One of the comments states that `Show` doesn't display a graphic, but merges the display of several `Graphics` objects. Perhaps this is the reason why `plotgrid` doesn't work within my for loop. But this still doesn't explain why it works outside the for loop...

```
(* Initialise random array of points *)
start[n_] := Table[{Random[], Random[]}, {i, n}, {j, n}];

(* Update the network, using learning coefficients lamda and gamma *)


update[state_, lamda_, gamma_] := 
 Module[{a, b, c, n}, n = Length[state];

  a = {Random[], Random[]}; (* random input point *)

  (* find unit closest to input point *)
  b = Table[(state[[i, j]] - a).(state[[i, j]] - a), {i, n}, {j, n}];
  c = Position[b, Min[b]][[1]];

  (* update winning unit and its 4 neighbours *)
  b = state;
  b[[c[[1]], c[[2]]]] += lamda (a - b[[c[[1]], c[[2]]]]);
  If[c[[1]] > 1, 
   b[[c[[1]] - 1, c[[2]]]] += gamma*(a - b[[c[[1]] - 1, c[[2]]]])]; 
  If[c[[1]] < n, 
   b[[c[[1]] + 1, c[[2]]]] += gamma*(a - b[[c[[1]] + 1, c[[2]]]])];
  If[c[[2]] > 1, 
   b[[c[[1]], c[[2]] - 1]] += gamma*(a - b[[c[[1]], c[[2]] - 1]])]; 
  If[c[[2]] < n, 
   b[[c[[1]], c[[2]] + 1]] += gamma*(a - b[[c[[1]], c[[2]] + 1]])];

  b (* return updated network *)]


(* Plot 2-D array for Kohonen net as grid of lines *) 
plotgrid[state_] := Module[{a, n}, n = Length[state];
  a = {};
  Do[a = Append[a, Line[{state[[i, j]], state[[i + 1, j]]}]], {i, 
    n - 1}, {j, n}];
  Do[a = Append[a, Line[{state[[i, j]], state[[i, j + 1]]}]], {i, 
    n}, {j, n - 1}];
  Show[Graphics[a]]]

(* Random 3 x 3 array of points *) 
a = start[3];

For[iter = 1, iter < 100, iter++,

 (*Set values of learning coefficients*)
 lamda = 1/(1 + Log[10, iter]);
 gamma = 0.5*lamda;

 a = update[a, lamda, gamma];

 (* This plot doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why *)
 plotgrid[a]]

(* This plot is working *)
plotgrid[a]
```

Comment: Try `Monitor[For[...your loop...; Pause[0.1];plt=plotgrid[a]], plt]`. If you don't actually need to watch it, you can also do something like `(Reap@For[...your loop...;Sow[plotgrid[a]]])[[-1,-1]]`

Comment: `For` never returns anything.  You could use `Print@plotgrid` to see each plot, but really you want to use `Table` instead of `For` which will give (display) a list of all the results.

Comment: @george2079 I didn't know for doesn't return! Thanks. But I'd prefer to have a graphical display of the results if possible, rather than a table. Do you have any suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: @N.J.Evans That is what I was looking for. This is helpful and works well.

Comment: once you have a `Table` you can use `Grid` , `GraphicsGrid` , `MultiColumn` , .. to make it look nice.